# PHP get the first post separately from array returned by wpdb->get_results()

Tags: php, array

Apologies if the title isn't clear, can't quite think how to word this.

I'm getting a pretty standard list of posts like this:

```
    $pageposts=$wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' 
            ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 6
        ", OBJECT);
    $firstpost = array_shift($pageposts);
```

But this isn't returning what I expect. Instead of `$firstpost` conatining the first post in the array `$pageposts` (like the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) say it should), it contains the oldest - and `$pageposts` still also contains that post (which it shouldn't according to the docs), however the latest post is missing. I don't know what the Gordon Bennet is going on with this, I've also tried `array_pop()` which should do the opposite of `array_shift()`, but with similarly strange results (latest post shown but `$firstpost` still contains the wrong value).

OK I've waffled on a bit, so to conclude, here's what I'm trying to do:
I want to make a single query, get the result, and print out the latest post in one area of the page and then the rest of the posts in another area. Trouble is, in the HTML, the older posts come before the one new post, so I need to split it into a separate variable and make sure the older posts don't show this new one with the others.

Does this make sense?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: just occurred to me that this is probably better asked on SO as it's more to do with PHP, so I'll post it there instead. thanks anyway :)

Comment: use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) please

Comment: @Soulseekah why? is it more efficient, or should I be using it because I'm not doing anything it doesn't do already?

Comment: You're avoiding caching, for one. And as you grow it, you are bound to miss some input sanitization. `get_posts` is more readable and easier to use. If you're not working with a 10000000000 page requests without caching you'll barely notice any difference between raw SQL. Building on the efficiency logic, why don't you `mysql_query` instead? That's even more efficient, no?

Comment: Fair points, I'll switch to get_posts, thanks. Also I've figured out my problem atleast as far as array_shift goes - it does exactly what it should do. I have an error where I'm outputting the data, time to go and debug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you have set of result in particular order you can achieve it simply as below : -

```
$pageposts=$wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' 
            ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 6
        ", OBJECT);
```

First time

```
$i=1;
foreach($pageposts as $pageposts_first){
//here goes your first post
if($i==1) break;
}
```

For rest of posts

```
$i=0;
foreach($pageposts as $pageposts_rest){
 $i++;
   if($i==1) continue;
  //here goes you rest of posts
}
```

You can do same thing even if you use get_posts instead..

Comment: yep, that helped me, thanks :) feel a bit dense now lol

Comment: @jammypeach Sometime its good to think simple!!!